# Cocoapods: How to enable OS_OBJECT_USE_OBJC? (GCD queues as proper ObjC objects)

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, grand-central-dispatch, cocoapods

The [`OS_OBJECT_USE_OBJC`](http://opensource.apple.com/source/libdispatch/libdispatch-228.18/os/object.h) flag denotes that GrandCentralDispath queues (and probably other OS objects?) are fully compliant Objective-C objects (so they managed by ARC, etc.)

If I do

```
#if OS_OBJECT_USE_OBJC
    NSLog(@"OS_OBJECT_USE_OBJC=1")
#else
    NSLog(@"OS_OBJECT_USE_OBJC=0");
#endif
```

From the *AppDelegate* I see `OS_OBJECT_USE_OBJC=1`. However, doing the same within the code of any Pod shows `OS_OBJECT_USE_OBJC=0`. The first line of my *Podfile* is

```
platform :ios, '7.0'
```

and omitting that line doesn't seem to make a difference. My *Base SDK* is iOS 8.0 and my `Deployment Target` is iOS 7.0.

How can I "enable" `OS_OBJECT_USE_OBJC` for my pods?

Also, is there any official documentation explaining `OS_OBJECT_USE_OBJC`? I couldn't find any.

Comment: Care to explain the downvote? I think this is a reasonable question.

Comment: Have you tried specifying `deployment_target`? In the Cocoapods documentation, all discussion of `OS_OBJECT_USE_OBJC` is associated with the `deployment_target` settings, not the `platform` settings.

Comment: I think `deployment_target` is only used within Podspecs and cannot be used in a Podfile. Incidentally, my pod project targets' have 7.0 as the `Deployment target`. I think there must be an additional setting around the build settings that is opting out of GDC ObjC objects.

Comment: Reported this a Cocoapods bug [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2659).

Comment: Me too. Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pods that specify a deployment target of < iOS 6.0 or OS X < 10.8 on their `.podspec` file, will have `OS_OBJECT_USE_OBJC = 0` regardless of the `Deployment Target`set on app using the pod.

See [here](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#deployment_target) and [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2659) for more info.

Comment: Unfortunately for me, this is set to 0 even for pods whose specs have a deployment target set at iOS 6.0 or higher. This appears to have happened to all my pods.